# MySQL having clause with where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which is used to populate a dropdown:

```
SELECT order_details.od_no, order_details.so_number, sales-order.status, sales-order.so-no, products.product_name 
FROM order_details 
LEFT JOIN sales-order ON order_details.so_number = sales-order.so-number 
LEFT JOIN products ON order_details.product_id = products.product_id 
WHERE order_details.so_number = '$sonum' AND sales-order.status != 'Canceled' 
HAVING SUM(po_prod_qty) < quantity
```

I have researched that aggregate `SUM()` will only work in `HAVING` clause if I want it to act like it's in a `WHERE` clause. But this query isn't working. Am I missing something?

Comment: replace `WHERE` by `AND`.

Comment: If quantity column is not specified in select list then you will have an error like *Unknown column 'quantity' in 'having clause'*

Answer (score 1):

You are perhaps missing a `group by` clause, if you really want to use `sum()`.  The use of the `sum()` in `having` creates an aggregation query, which returns just one row.  You may not need an aggregation at, if this does what you want:

```
SELECT od.od_no, od.so_number, so.status, so.so-no, p.product_name 
FROM order_details od LEFT JOIN
     sales_order so
     ON od.so_number = so.so-number  LEFT JOIN
     products p
     ON od.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE od.so_number = '$sonum' AND so.status <> 'Canceled' and po_prod_qty < quantity;
```

Otherwise, it is hard to say exactly what you want without sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the same field and use `group by` clause

```
SELECT SUM(po_prod_qty) as prod_qty, ....
```